# Thinnest 2-fold coverings of the plane by congruent convex shapes

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling

It is an unsolved problem to determine the "thinnest" $2$-fold covering of 
the plane by disks.
The $2$-fold coverage problem by disks is to find the minimum number of congruent
(unit-radius) disks such that each point of the plane is covered by at least $2$ disks.
Here is a paper from 1997 on the topic, including their Fig.1 showing the thinnest
$1$-fold covering and a potential thinnest $2$-fold covering:

> Bezdek, András, and Włodzimierz Kuperberg. "Circle covering with a margin." 
>   *Periodica Mathematica Hungarica* 34.1-2 (1997): 3-16.
>   [journal link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1004275121878)
>
> ---
>
> [image: BezdekKuperbergFig1]

---

And here is a paper from just a few days ago on this topic, which says that
thinnest $k$-fold disk coverage for $k>1$ is "hopelessly difficult":

> Jingchao Chen.
>   "Two-Fold Circle-Covering of the Plane under Congruent Voronoi Polygon Conditions."
>   3 Oct 2014.
>   [arXiv Abstract link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1372)

My question is:

> **Q**. For which shapes $K$ (planar convex bodies)
>   is the thinnest $2$-fold covering (by congruent copies of $K$) known?

I would allow $K$ to be rigidly transformed: translated, rotated.
Certainly if $K$ tiles the plane, the question is settled.
So for all triangles, and for all quadrilaterals 
(see [this earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/180751/6094)),
matters are settled.
[Some pentagons tile the plane](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/tile/pentagon.html).
How about for $K$ a regular pentagon? Etc.
(*Added*:). I am especially interested to learn if some thinnest $2$-fold
covering is known for a shape that does not perfectly tile the plane.

Comment: There are must be nice *non*-convex polygons which do not tile the plane but do give perfect $2$-coverings (  $2/3$ of a hexagon, chosen wisely?) If you could tile one of those with a convex non-plane tiler you would be set.

Comment: My example does tile $2/3$ of a hexagon but not in the way you imagined...

Comment: this is about teh case when only translations are allowed: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00493-012-2860-3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[*Edited* to add a two-parameter family of hexagons]

Here's a family of convex pentagons $K_\epsilon$, each of which
does not tile the plane but does have a perfect $2$-covering
by rotated translates.

Start with a regular hexagon $\,\widetilde{\!H}$.
Its six shorter diagonals form a "star of David" with a smaller hexagon
$H$ at its center whose area is $1/3$ the area of $\,\widetilde{\!H}$.
Now tile the plane with parallel copies of $\,\widetilde{\!H}$,
and remove the corresponding copy of $H$ from the center of each translate.
The resulting region, call it $R$, is shown shaded in the first part
of the image below (with $\,\widetilde{\!H}$ and its translates
outlined in blue, and the star of David in light blue).
This picture shows how $R$ is also the hexagonal tiling by copies of $H$
with every third hexagon removed.  Hence three parallel copies of $R$
constitute a perfect $2$-covering of the plane.

[image]

Now each copy of $\,\widetilde{\!H} - H$ is tiled by
six rotations of a pentagon $K_0$ with angles
$120^\circ, 90^\circ, 120^\circ, 90^\circ, 120^\circ$.
So $K_0$ has a perfect $2$-covering.  This is not yet our pentagon:
it tiles the plane, because three copies fill $H$ exactly.
But we can deform $K_0$ by rotating its shortest two sides
by $\epsilon$ degrees to a pentagon $K_\epsilon$,
with angles $(120+\epsilon)^\circ, (90-\epsilon)^\circ,
120^\circ, (90+\epsilon)^\circ, (120-\epsilon)^\circ$,
six copies of which still tile $\,\widetilde{\!H} - H$
as shown in the second part of the image.  For small but
nonzero $\epsilon$ this $K_\epsilon$ cannot tile the plane,
not even with reflections allowed $-$ a contradiction is soon reached
starting with a neighborhood of a $(120\pm\epsilon)^\circ$ angle.
But $K_\epsilon$ still perfectly $2$-covers the plane
via $\,\widetilde{\!H}-H$ and $R$,
so we have our family of convex pentagons
with a minimal tiling thickness of $2$.

P.S. I later noticed a further modifiction to a two-parameter family of
convex hexagons $K = K_{\epsilon,\delta}$ that do not tile the plane
but do tile $R$ and thus perfectly $2$-cover the plane.  Deform each edge of
$\,\widetilde{\!H}$ to the same Z-shaped path ("Z-shaped":
centrally-symmetric concatenation of three line segments).
Call the resulting polygon $\,\widetilde{\!H}'$; it still tiles the plane.
Do not change $H$.  Then $\,\widetilde{\!H}' - H$ is tiled by
six rotations of the same convex hexagon $K$, as seen in the
first part of the next image:

[image]

Hence $K$ tiles $R$, as seen in the second part, and therefore
$K$ perfectly $2$-covers the plane.  Compared with the pentagons $K_\epsilon$,
this variation has the advantage not just of an extra parameter but also
that it's much easier to check there's no perfect $1$-covering:
If a convex hexagon tiles the plane then we can assume that
any two adjacent tiles must share a complete edge,
and that no more than three tiles meet in every corner;
and that's soon seen to be impossible here.

Comment: This is an exceptionally clever 2-tiling by an irregular pentagon. And I appreciate your lucid explanation and the precisely informative figures. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you!  I noticed later that there's
a further generalization to a 2-parameter family of convex hexagons;
see the new pictures.

Comment: Those hexagon 2-covers are pleasingly intricate, Noam! :-)

Comment: Are there convex regions which (i) do not perfectly tile the plane, (ii) cannot form a perfect 2-cover of the plane but (ii) can form a perfect 3-cover of the plane? And one can push 3 in this question to n.